# How to cache audio, video and image from server and save in internal memory?

Tags: android

I am working on tablet application. My requirement is to download audio, video and images (approx 20-30 MB data) from server and store in internal memory. So next time user do not need to download data again.

I found some library which will download and save image in cache memory.
Does anybody know some library which will download all format of file and save in memory. Also which will handle memory issue.

Thanks

Comment: The DefaultHttpClient class can download any file from the internet. After that you can read InputStream and save it anywhere. I doubt that there are libraries which can do all this work instead of you.

Comment: yes I can do that..but how to handle memory?

Comment: I just start a new thread in the Application.onCreate method that checks whether the folder with cached files is larger than 25Mb and clears  it if it is necessary. But it doesn't seem to be a good way, maybe someone really knows how to handle this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache
" A cache that uses a bounded amount of space on a filesystem. Values are byte sequences, accessible as streams or files"

Answer (score 1):

[AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) allows stream and cache video simultaneously.